# Is it possible to implement nested modal in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to implement nested modal dialogs (modal in modal) in lwc. Have tried a few but the result doesn't seem to be awesome. In react, there seems to be some library for layering. But I don't see similar things in lwc.

Is that possible in lwc?

Comment: Checkout - https://salesforcecodes.blogspot.com/2020/01/how-to-display-modal-window-using.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SLDS spec allows for nested modals (modal in modal) when using `overlayLibrary`. Unfortunately, there is currently no LWC equivalent for `overlayLibrary` just yet.

However, the official recipe repo has submitted this stopgap while we wait for an equivalent:

https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/issues/57

You can inspect the pull request, but even with this, I am not sure if double modal will work even in this recipe.